# Maven tomcat7-maven-plugin not work with @WebServlet

Tags: maven, servlet-3.0, tomcat7-maven-plugin

I create a `Servlet` in servlet3.0 with `@WebSevlet` like this:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/demo2"}, loadOnStartup = 1)
public class Demo2Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("[Demo2Servlet][work]");
    }
}
```

And I add plugin `tomcat7-maven-plugin` in maven like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>8080</port>
        <path>/web30</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

when I use command `tomcat7:run`, it give me an error:

```
Fatal: Servlet /web30 threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: demo2.sevlet.Demo2Servlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
.......
```

But if I **use tomcat7 in Local, it works well**, Why?

what I don't understand is why the error is `ClassCastException`, I extends the HttpServlet!!

=======================================================================
thanks to @Vikdor, you are quite right, add `<scope>provided</scope>` in servlet-api dependency, it works wonderful.

Comment: what is servlet-api version in you are using?

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: have you tried marking the servlet-api dependency with scope as `provided`?

Comment: thx guys, add `<scope>provided</scope>` can solve this problem :)

Comment: Hi, would you please tell me where to add the <scope>? I tried adding the servlet api to the pom of my project and it didn't work.